# What files make one Wordpress site different from another

Tags: database, wordpress, migration, cpanel, mediatemple

Migrating wordpress sites between hosts can take a lot of time, especially when the hosting platforms are different.

I have been trying to migrate my sites from Cpanel to Mediatemple, but it seems like im just not getting it right.

There is various options

1. Use the guide they provide
   https://kb.mediatemple.net/questions/1556/Migrating+your+websites+to+the+Grid#gs

   - When moving the files in this way the permissions of the files are not set properly and I would have to got back through them and figure out which ones need to change.
   - The database export from PHPMyAdmin also does not look the same it looks in the screenshot
2. Using InfiniteWP

   - To use InfiniteWP you must provide the url of the site and since I dont want to change the DNS until the site is moved this option does not seems to be ideal.
   - This option might work if its ok for the sites to be unavailable for a day or so while the DNS resolves...
   - But I don't want the sites to be unavailable
3. Using Mediatemples "one click apps" to install wordpress and then moving only the files that are unique to the site from the old host to the new host.

   - I would like to use this option
   - I think that the content of the WP-Content folder needs to be moved that the database needs to be moved.

My question is 
- what folders and files in a standard wordpress install typically hardly ever changes from one site to the other.
- can I use the wordpress database export and import function to move the database from one site to the other.

Any help will be appreciated

Thank you

Comment: what theme ( and plugins ) are you using? If its something custom with its own post types etc, builtin wordpress export-import might not be enough. You would want to use phpmyadmin to export/import the entire database and make changes to the data to account for a different database name, links in content, site url and so on. The folders wp-admin and wp-includes depend on the wordpress version and wp-content is where all your custom content is stored. The files wp-config.php and .htaccess are the one's that are specific to the site. If this all sounds too complicated, hire a developer.

Answer (score 0):

With InfiniteWP, you can use the *clone an existing site* command (which can be found in "Tool"->"Install / Clone WP") to migrate a site to a new server.
You have to use a temporary (sub)domain pointing to the new server.

To answer your questions :

1. `/wp-content/` stores all your files and sometimes plugin files, `wp-config.php` is where your configuration is stored (e.g. credentials to access the database). Depending on your servers, the `.htaccess` files may be different.
2. I would recommend to create a dump file of your entire database using phpMyAdmin.